# Values will not calculate correctly

Tags: python

i'm trying to take a list then using a function compute the scrabble score. That part i think i have working.

Then i need to run the list through another function that creates a dictionary with the word as the key and the scrabble score function as the value.

It works, but it seems to only be calling the first letter in the words score, although it works separately.

I'm in week 5 of Python at my CC so we haven't used recursion or any other advanced methods, this is for the function chapter.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong so I can learn from it.

I've rewritten the functions several times and "walked" through them on paper, so obviously i'm missing something fundamental.

```
word_dict = dict()
def computeScrabbleScore(word_list):
    letter_values = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f':4, 'g': 2, 'h':4, 'i':1,'j':8, 'k':5,
                 'l':1, 'm':3, 'n':1, 'o':1, 'p':3, 'q':10, 'r':1, 's':1, 't':1, 'u':1,'v':8, 'w':4,
                 'x':8, 'y':4, 'z':10}

    for word in word_list:
        score = 0
        word = word.lower()
        #print(word)
        for letter in word:
            score += letter_values[letter]  
        #print(score,'*')
        return score

def wordScore(word_list):
# Use the variable word_dict for the (word,word score) dictionary.
    for word in word_list:
        word_dict[word] = computeScrabbleScore(word)
    return word_dict

wlist = 
['Half','a','league','half','a','league','Half','a','league','onward',
     'All','in','the','valley','of','Death','Rode','the','six','hundred',
     'Forward','the','Light','Brigade','Charge','for','the','guns','he','said',
     'Into','the','valley','of','Death','Rode','the','six','hundred']
#word_dict = wordScore(word_list)
#t = computeScrabbleScore(wlist)
#print(score)
x = wordScore(wlist)
print(x)
```

Comment: Is your original code indented like that? letter_values and the for should be in the computeScrabbleScore function! = indented more to the right

Comment: Your definition looks like this: `def computeScrabbleScore(word_list)`, but you call this function with a single word as an argument (`computeScrabbleScore(word)`), not a _list_ of words. Looks like there's a flaw in the logic.

Comment: When you paste code into a question (or answer), immediately select what you just pasted and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface to format the code properly and avoid introducing indentation errors by trying to manually fix it.

Comment: you're returning too early due to indentation...look carefully at the line `return score`

Comment: In `wordScore` you call `computeScrabbleScore(word)`, but you define `computeScrabbleScore` as taking `word_list` not a single `word`.  Inside the function you do `for word in word_list`, but `word_list` is the word you passed in, so at this point you are iterating by letter.  Then when you do `for letter in word:` you are iterating over a single letter word.  Since you return after that loop you are giving the score of a single letter.

Comment: Did you notice that the `print(word)` in `computeScrabbleScore` printed only single characters, not entire words? Work your way backwards from there, verifying all your assumptions. (Is `word` really a word? Is `word_list` really a list of words?).

Answer (score 0):

It think the `score` variable should have been before the loop:

```
word_dict = dict()
def computeScrabbleScore(word):
    letter_values = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f':4, 'g': 2, 'h':4, 'i':1,'j':8, 'k':5,
                     'l':1, 'm':3, 'n':1, 'o':1, 'p':3, 'q':10, 'r':1, 's':1, 't':1, 'u':1,'v':8, 'w':4,
                     'x':8, 'y':4, 'z':10}

    score = 0
    word = word.lower()

    for letter in word:
        score += letter_values[letter]
    #print(score,'*')
    return score

def wordScore(word_list):
    # Use the variable word_dict for the (word,word score) dictionary.
    for word in word_list:
        word_dict[word] = computeScrabbleScore(word)
    return word_dict

wlist = ['Half','a','league','half','a','league','Half','a','league','onward',
     'All','in','the','valley','of','Death','Rode','the','six','hundred',
     'Forward','the','Light','Brigade','Charge','for','the','guns','he','said',
     'Into','the','valley','of','Death','Rode','the','six','hundred']
#word_dict = wordScore(word_list)
#t = computeScrabbleScore(wlist)
#print(score)
x = wordScore(wlist)
print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'Death': 9, 'Charge': 12, 'in': 2, 'Forward': 14, 'Brigade': 11, 'said': 5, 'for': 6, 'onward': 10, 'Half': 10, 'hundred': 12, 'guns': 5, 'Light': 9, 'half': 10, 'six': 10, 'he': 5, 'a': 1, 'league': 7, 'All': 3, 'valley': 16, 'of': 5, 'Into': 4, 'Rode': 5, 'the': 6}
```

Comment: You fail to note the difference between the call `computeScrabbleScore(word)` and the definition `computeScrabbleScore(word_list)`.  You don't mention that you changed the indentation of the return statement.  You didn't mention that the nested loops were unnecessary nor did you fix them.  Your answer is poor because it doesn't fix what needs fixing, doesn't explain what's wrong, and doesn't fully point out what changed.